# basic constructor usage in java

Tags: java, constructor

For whatever reason, I cannot find this question anywhere else, nor can I find the answer online.  If I have the following:

```
package temp1;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public MainClass(int radius_x, int area_x, int circumference_x) {
        int radius = radius_x;
        int area = area_x;
        int circumference = circumference_x;
    }

}
```

Assuming that this is even correct usage, then how would I actually *use* the variables defined in the constructor here?  They only work inside of the constructor thanks to scope.

Comment: You declare them in a larger scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the code you supply makes little sense. A more common scenario is to use the constructor to initialize a few instance variables, which can then be used throughout the class.

```
public class MainClass {
    private int radius;
    private int area;
    private int circumference;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public MainClass(int radius_x, int area_x, int circumference_x) {
         this.radius = radius_x;
         this.area = area_x;
         this.circumference = circumference_x;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes much more sense.  I was wondering because I am following an absolutely horrible textbook for Java in BlueJ because of a class in my highschool.  The textbook wanted me to define the variables in the constructor without declaring them anywhere else and doesn't show me how to use the variables afterwards.  I had the feeling it was doing something wrong, but I wanted to clarify.  In an earlier chapter it explicitly stated that do while and while were the same and had no advantages/disadvantages, so I'm not surprised to it's wrong again.  :)

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... out of curiosity, could you please provide the textbook's title or ISBN?

Comment: Blue Pelican Java by Charles E. Cook.

Comment: Excerpt: "The do-while loop:
A do-while loop is exactly the same as a while-loop except the control expression is at the
bottom of the loop rather that at the top as it is with the while-loop." (page 58 of the PDF document)

Comment: @Stopforgettingmyaccounts... well that's not incorrect, just potentially very confusing. Anyhow, googled it, read through some of the pdf and yes, doesn't look peachy. Hang in there :(

Comment: I have experience in programming and I'm familiar with the terms.  I often help my teacher because she majored in marketing and doesn't have much experience in Java.  I'll be fine, thanks for the concern ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way to re-use the arguments of your constructor is to have instance variables assigned with your constructor's arguments' values.

As such:

```
package temp1;

public class MainClass {

    private int radiusX;
    private int areaX;
    private int circumferenceX;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public MainClass(int radius_x, int area_x, int circumference_x) {
        this.radiusX = radius_x;
        this.areaX = area_x;
        this.circumferenceX = circumference_x;
    }
    // TODO getters [and setters] for instance variables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package temp1;

public class MainClass {

        int radius ;
        int area;
        int circumference;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public MainClass(int radius_x, int area_x, int circumference_x) {
        this.radius = radius_x;
        this.area = area_x;
        this.circumference = circumference_x;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a constructor, but the variables inside are only local to the constructor itself and not outside of it. To do this, you need class member fields:

```
public class MainClass {
    private int radius;
    private int area;
    private int circumference;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainClass m = new MainClass(5, 6, 7);
        System.out.println("The radius is " + m.getRadius());
    }

    public MainClass(int radius_x, int area_x, int circumference_x) {
         radius = radius_x;
         area = area_x;
         circumference = circumference_x;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(int area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public int getCircumference() {
        return circumference;
    }

    public void setCircumference(int circumference) {
        this.circumference = circumference;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind also there is no need to pass in `area_x` and `circumference_x` Those can be derived from `radius_x`. That's assuming you are being faithful to the meanings of the terms rather than just playing around with variables to learn the language.

Comment: area_x and circumference_x were intended to be used with methods that aren't written here, such as radiusFromArea and areaFromCircumference, etc. in case one or the other weren't known.